# init.h not installed

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kernel, kernel-modules, manjaro

So, I am trying to build a simple kernel module in manjaro. The following is the code

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

static int __init helloWorldInit(void)
{
    pr_info("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit helloWorldExit(void)
{
    pr_info("Removed kernel module successfully");
}

module_init(helloWorldInit);
module_exit(helloWorldExit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("author");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Test kernel module");
MODULE_VERSION("2:1.0");
```

and here is the makefile

```
obj-m += helloWorld.o
KDIR = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
all:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(shell pwd) modules
clean:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(shell pwd) clean
```

The problem is that even though I have installed the linux header file package (linux515-headers), init.h is not available among the header files. What should I do?

Comment: My guess is you need to tell the compilers which directories to loook into for headers, using the `-I` flag